# Test multiple iOS Devices with Xcode Server

Tags: ios, xcode, appium, osx-server, xcode-server

It is possible to test multiple IOS devices with OSX Server and Xcode Server.

https://developer.apple.com/videos/wwdc/2014/
Continuous Integration with Xcode 6

I hope I have understood the problem correctly.

The Problem with test multiple IOS devices is. That instruments can run only one device at a time.

With XCode Server it should bepossible to run more then one device at the same time.

Has anyone tried this?

Can Appium handle multiple sessions out of the box or Appium changes are required?

https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/IDEs/Conceptual/xcode_guide-continuous_integration/000-About_Continuous_Integration/about_continuous_integration.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP400132921

Comment: I don't think this is possible at the moment. The only realistic solution might be to run multiple VMs of the OS with a different instance of Xcode Server on each, but I've never tried that.

Comment: I have the same problem. If you found some solution please share it